# Determine if a listbox item has been selected with an if...then...else statement

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to have a menu item remove a selected item from a listbox, and display a message warning the user if they didn't select an item to be removed. 
This is what I have so far:

```
    If Me.lstFacts.SelectedItem = "Something"  Then
        Me.lstFacts.Items.Remove(Me.lstFacts.SelectedItem)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item!")
    End If
```

I'm determining what items are added to the list with an input box:

```
    Dim intCounter As Integer 'Counter

    Do While intCounter < 5
        Dim strFact As String = InputBox("Add new fact")
        Me.lstFacts.Items.Add(strFact)
        intCounter += 1
    Loop
```

I just need to know what to replace the "something" with in the loop. I tried setting it to strFact, but since strFact is determined in a different menu item and therefore a different scope, I can't use it.

Comment: `strFact` doesnt just have procedure level scope, it has block scope.  Even with form level scope, it appears to be a temp var so it would only ever hold the last value added.  You cant check for specific item text because *they* selected it.  Check if there *are* any selected items (based on the nag code).

Comment: I tried doing:  If Me.lstFacts.SelectedItem = "" but that didn't work. Is there a way for me to check if the selected item is equal to any string of characters?  I just need to make sure an item was selected in general. I can't tell it exactly what to be equal to since the list options are dependent on what the user enters.

Comment: Define "that didn't work"

Comment: When I use the "remove" menu item after selecting an item from the list, it tells me "Please select an item" as if nothing were selected.

Comment: First, if it even compiles, you need to set `Option Strict On`.  `SelectedItem` is an Object - you may have put strings in there, but it can hold almost anything - and you cannot compare 2 different types directly.  So, of course if anything is selected it will not be `""` (String.Empty) and your nag msg appears.  Check `If lstFacts.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing`. You can find gobs of info on the things you are working with by putting the cursor on `SelectedItem` and pressing the magical key [F1]

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks for all the help.